# Some blank properties missing

Tags: support, api, associated

I am using [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/associated). I haven't posted any question in one account, so the response comes as:

```
"top_questions": [],
"top_answers": [],
"question_count": 0,
"answer_count": 0,
```

in the same browser window. Snapshot: [image: snapshot is added for reference].

Also in application, it gives the same results. But when I send the request in the address bar of new tab of browser, then the response comes as:

```
"question_count":0,
"answer_count":0,
```

Snapshot: [image: snapshot is added for reference].

The above two response elements (top_questions & top_answers) are absent now. Why? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4):

See [the documentation for `network_user`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user).   `top_answers` and `top_questions` are not returned by default; you must specify them explicitly in a filter.

When you ran [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users#filter=!-*f%286r3ZbZjn) from the doc page and from your app, you used a filter (`!-*f(6r3ZbZjn`) that specified those two properties.

When you used the address bar of the browser, you didn't specify a filter, so the default was used which doesn't return those 2 properties.

If you use a direct link with an appropriate filter specified, EG:
  [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/6482771/associated?filter=!-*f(6r3ZbZjn](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/6482771/associated?filter=!-*f(6r3ZbZjn)
you get the expected results.

Comment: I checked it again & again. Its giving ambiguous

Comment: And yes, I am giving (`!-*f(6r3ZbZjn`) filter